# How to plot correlation graphs with R^2 for a big datamatrix?

Tags: r, ggplot2, correlation, facet

I have a proteomics data matrix. In the data matrix, I have detected a different number of peptides for each protein (detectable peptides numbers vary on the protein).

Q1. How can I plot correlation graphs for each protein to compare how its' peptides behave. i.e. For protein A, I have peptides a1-a3, I want to compare a1 vs a2, a1 vs a3, and a2 vs a3.

Sample data

```
structure(list(Protein = c("A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "C", "C", "D", "D", "D"), Peptide = c("a1", "a2", "a3", "a4", "b1", "c1", "c2", "d1", "d2", "d3"), Sample1 = c(0.275755732, 0.683048798, 1.244604878, 0.850270313, 0.492175199, 0.269651338, 0.393004954, 0.157966662, 1.681672581, 0.298308801), Sample2 = c(0.408992244, 0.172488244, 1.749247694, 0.358172308, 0.142129982, 0.158636283, 0.243500648, 0.095019037, 0.667928805, 0.572162278), Sample3 = c(0.112265765, 0.377174168, 2.430040623, 0.497873323, 0.141136584, 0.250330266, 0.249783164, 0.107188279, 0.173623439, 0.242298602), Sample4 = c(0.87688073, 0.841826338, 0.831376575, 0.985900966, 0.891632525, 1.016533723, 0.292048735, 0.776351689, 0.800070173, 1.161882923), Sample5 = c(1.034093889, 0.304305772, 0.616445765, 1.000820463, 1.03124071, 0.995897846, 0.289542364, 0.578721727, 0.672592766, 1.168944588), Sample6 = c(1.063124715, 0.623917522, 0.613196611, 0.990921045, 1.014340981, 0.965631141, 0.316793011, 1.02220535, 1.182063616, 1.41196421), Sample7 = c(1.335677026, 0.628621656, 0.411171453, 1.050563412, 1.290233552, 1.1603839, 0.445372411, 1.077192698, 0.726669337, 1.09453338), Sample8 = c(1.139360562, 0.404024829, 0.263714711, 0.899959209, 1.356913804, 1.246338203, 0.426568548, 1.104988267, 0.964924824, 1.083654341), Sample9 = c(1.38146599, 0.582817437, 0.783698738, 1.118948066, 1.010795866, 1.277086848, 0.434025911, 1.238871048, 1.201184368, 1.476478831), Sample10 = c(1.111486801, 0.60513273, 0.460680037, 1.385702246, 1.448873253, 1.364329784, 0.375032044, 1.382750002, 0.741842319, 1.035657705)), row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), spec = structure(list( cols = list(Protein = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", "collector")), Peptide = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", "collector")), Sample1 = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", "collector")), Sample2 = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", "collector")), Sample3 = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", "collector")), Sample4 = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", "collector")), Sample5 = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", "collector")), Sample6 = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", "collector")), Sample7 = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", "collector")), Sample8 = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", "collector")), Sample9 = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", "collector")), Sample10 = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", "collector"))), default = structure(list(), class = c("collector_guess", "collector"))), class = "col_spec"))
```

Hence peptide number varies for each protein, how can I compare each peptide and save the faceted graph into single plots, by this, I can select only required graphs.

Comment: what have you tried so far to resolve the problem? Perhaps, you can edit your post and show us what has already been tried.

Comment: I'm unable to connect your expected output with your sample data. Where in your sample data are the quantities C_low/high? What are the numbers in the facet strips? Where is depth in your sample data? Please edit your question to provide expected output **based on your sample data**.

Comment: Thanks Dr. Evers. No this plot is just added to show what I 'm expecting, but I can not do this since peptide number varies for each proteins. So some comparisons are useless (e.g. a1 vs b1). I wan to compare only the peptides of particular protein. I will remove this graph if this is confusing.

Comment: also see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10239497/ggplot2scatterplots-for-all-possible-combinations-of-variables)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*"Hence peptide number varies for each protein, how can I compare each peptide and save the faceted graph into single plots, by this, I can select only required graphs."* I'm not entirely sure *what* you actually want to plot. A correlation plot of which quantities? Select only *which* required graphs?

Anyway, perhaps the following will help.

```
library(GGally)
library(tidyverse)
df %>%
    gather(Sample, Value, -Protein, -Peptide) %>%
    spread(Peptide, Value) %>%
    filter(Protein == "A") %>%
    ggpairs(columns = 3:6)
```

[image]

Explanation: We reshape data such that we have `Value`s for every `Peptide` in columns; then we filter entries for `Protein == "A"` and use `GGally::ggpairs` to show pairwise correlation plots of `Value`s for every `Peptide`.

You have a lot of flexibility in customising the output plot of `ggpairs` (e.g. add regression lines, remove panels, etc.); I recommend taking a look at the [GGally GitHub project page](http://ggobi.github.io/ggally/) and at [Multiple regression lines in ggpairs](https://www.r-bloggers.com/multiple-regression-lines-in-ggpairs/).

---

### Update

If you want to show correlation plots only for certain `Peptide`s, you could do the following

```
pep_of_interest <- c("a2", "a4")
df %>%
    gather(Sample, Value, -Protein, -Peptide) %>%
    spread(Peptide, Value) %>%
    filter(Protein == "A") %>%
    ggpairs(columns = match(pep_of_interest, colnames(.)))
```

[image]

Comment: try this to get all plots per protein in a list: `res <- d %>% 
  gather(k,v, -Protein, -Peptide) %>% 
  split(.$Protein) %>% 
  map(~spread(.,Peptide, v)) %>% 
  map(~select(.,-1:-2) %>% ggpairs(.))`

Comment: Thanks alot Dr. Evers! Appreciate as always :)

Comment: As always, you're very welcome @Oncidium ;-) Good luck with your work!

Comment: @Dr. Evers, This package is awesome. Thanks for your answer. One quick question, my working df is large one. After reshape the data, what is the easiest way to find the location of my interested protein (peptides), i.e. here you select 3:6 ggpairs(columns = 3:6) ; how can I easily find where my location then!

Comment: @Jimbou Thank you and this is very helpful. I have two Qs if you could help me with; Q1. How can I add protein name to the plots and save these plots separately in a folder?
Q2. How can I gather plots that belong to one protein faceted and save?

Comment: @Oncidium I've updated my answer with an example how to show correlation plots only for certain peptides of interest. Please take a look.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution using the `corrplot` library if you are looking for visual representation of correlation. A lot more plotting options are available in the library (take a look at the [corrplot vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/corrplot/vignettes/corrplot-intro.html)).

```
# sample data
dd <- structure(list(Protein = c("A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "C", "C", "D", "D", "D"), Peptide = c("a1", "a2", "a3", "a4", "b1", "c1", "c2", "d1", "d2", "d3"), Sample1 = c(0.275755732, 0.683048798, 1.244604878, 0.850270313, 0.492175199, 0.269651338, 0.393004954, 0.157966662, 1.681672581, 0.298308801), Sample2 = c(0.408992244, 0.172488244, 1.749247694, 0.358172308, 0.142129982, 0.158636283, 0.243500648, 0.095019037, 0.667928805, 0.572162278), Sample3 = c(0.112265765, 0.377174168, 2.430040623, 0.497873323, 0.141136584, 0.250330266, 0.249783164, 0.107188279, 0.173623439, 0.242298602), Sample4 = c(0.87688073, 0.841826338, 0.831376575, 0.985900966, 0.891632525, 1.016533723, 0.292048735, 0.776351689, 0.800070173, 1.161882923), Sample5 = c(1.034093889, 0.304305772, 0.616445765, 1.000820463, 1.03124071, 0.995897846, 0.289542364, 0.578721727, 0.672592766, 1.168944588), Sample6 = c(1.063124715, 0.623917522, 0.613196611, 0.990921045, 1.014340981, 0.965631141, 0.316793011, 1.02220535, 1.182063616, 1.41196421), Sample7 = c(1.335677026, 0.628621656, 0.411171453, 1.050563412, 1.290233552, 1.1603839, 0.445372411, 1.077192698, 0.726669337, 1.09453338), Sample8 = c(1.139360562, 0.404024829, 0.263714711, 0.899959209, 1.356913804, 1.246338203, 0.426568548, 1.104988267, 0.964924824, 1.083654341), Sample9 = c(1.38146599, 0.582817437, 0.783698738, 1.118948066, 1.010795866, 1.277086848, 0.434025911, 1.238871048, 1.201184368, 1.476478831), Sample10 = c(1.111486801, 0.60513273, 0.460680037, 1.385702246, 1.448873253, 1.364329784, 0.375032044, 1.382750002, 0.741842319, 1.035657705)), row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), spec = structure(list( cols = list(Protein = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", "collector")), Peptide = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", "collector")), Sample1 = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", "collector")), Sample2 = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", "collector")), Sample3 = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", "collector")), Sample4 = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", "collector")), Sample5 = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", "collector")), Sample6 = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", "collector")), Sample7 = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", "collector")), Sample8 = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", "collector")), Sample9 = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", "collector")), Sample10 = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", "collector"))), default = structure(list(), class = c("collector_guess", "collector"))), class = "col_spec"))

# for Protein A, build subset of data
tempdd <- dd[dd$Protein == "A",][,-1]
cc <- tempdd[,1]
tempdd <- t(tempdd[,-1])
colnames(tempdd) <- cc

# calculate the correlations for all samples
rr <- cor(tempdd)

# install.packages("corrplot")
library(corrplot)

#Build the plot
corrplot(rr,method='circle')
```

[image]