# arrow() in ggplot2 no longer supported

Tags: r, ggplot2, r-grid

Installed R 2.15.2 on a new machine and ggplot2.  The grid package is no longer supported in this latest version of R, but ggplot2 uses grid for the `arrow()` function, as in these examples.

http://docs.ggplot2.org/current/geom_segment.html

Haven't been able to find a workaround.  Any suggestions?

Comment: Where did you hear that `grid` is no longer supported?  What does `library(grid)` print?  (Those examples work fine for me with 2.15.2, and if `grid` really had been dropped, `ggplot2` wouldn't work at all!)

Comment: When I try to install "grid" from within Eclipse, I get the following error.

> install.packages("grid")
Warning message:
package 'grid' is not available (for R version 2.15.2) 

Even though ggplot2 is installed, ?arrow gives

> ?arrow
No documentation for 'arrow' in specified packages and libraries:
you c

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Maybe you think that `grid` is no more supported because of the message displayed [on its CRAN page](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/grid/index.html) ? But if it is written that *Package ‘grid’ was removed from the CRAN repository*, it is because it is now part of the base R distribution, as mentioned on [Paul Murrell's `grid` page](http://www.stat.auckland.ac.nz/~paul/grid/grid.html).

So `library(grid)` and the `arrow` function should work fine.

Some of the confusion may be due to the fact that `grid` was loaded automatically by previous versions of `ggplot` (making `grid` functions visible/accessible to the user); now it's referred to via NAMESPACE imports instead, so you need to explicitly load `grid` if you want to use `grid` functions (or look at their help pages).

Comment: May I suggest that if a poster answers your question you use the check mark (will appear green) to indicate so.