# Error: could not find function "unit"

Tags: r, ggplot2

While trying to modify theme settings this simple code gives the following error:

```
library(ggplot2)
theme_nogrid <- theme_set(theme_update(  
                  plot.margin=unit(c(.25, .25, .25, .25), "in"),))

Error in do.call(theme, list(...)) : could not find function "unit"
```

`R` gives me this error for any element that uses 'unit'. Any other settings that do not call 'unit' work fine. I am running R v.2.15.2 (64-bit Windows).

I extensively searched online about this problem and found nothing. 
I appreciate any suggestions to the problem.

Comment: `require(grid)`

Comment: ggplot2 now imports grid, as opposed to loading it

Comment: Same thing happens with lattice. Somebody ought to right an answer so it can get checked. It deserves to be "on the record".

Comment: Same thing happened with 'methods' too have a look:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30266732/error-in-initfieldsscales-scales-could-not-find-function-initreffields 
Is it the case that the current version of ggplot (I work with 1.0.1) is importing some packages instead of loading them?
I believe a comprehensive answer by someone with a knowledge of the inners of gglot should be in place.

Answer (score 72):

This is closely related to, although not exactly identical to, [arrow() in ggplot2 no longer supported](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14677035/arrow-in-ggplot2-no-longer-supported) , which says:

> [the] `grid` [package] was loaded automatically by previous versions of `ggplot[2]` (making
>   `grid` functions visible/accessible to the user); now it's referred to
>   via `NAMESPACE` imports instead, so you need to explicitly load `grid` if
>   you want to use `grid` functions (or [to] look at their help pages).

"explicitly load" here means `library("grid")` or `require("grid")` (`grid` is a base package, so doesn't need to be installed separately).

`unit()` is a function from the `grid` package, so the answer above (which was about `arrow()`) applies.

Alternatively you can specify `grid::unit(...)` or `grid::arrow(...)` without explicitly loading the entire package.

Comment: Definitely closely related, something similar happened to me with 'methods' too. Take a look:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30266732/error-in-initfieldsscales-scales-could-not-find-function-initreffields/30292677