# Multiple ggplot object saved to Global environment from a for loop

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to save multiple ggplot objects (choropleth maps) into the Global Environment for subsequent use. My idea is to get the individual ggplots named as "Plot1", "Plot2", .... I am using the following code (simplified, as the choroplets have a complicated syntax):

```
for( i in 1:length(VARIABLES)) {
  plotname <- paste("Plot",i, sep = "")
  #
  plotdata <- melt(data = map.df, id.vars = c(....), measure.vars = VARIABLES[i])
  #
  eval(plotname) <- ggplot(  .... multi-line command.... )

}
```

The problem is with the "eval(plotname)" part: If I delete it, the loop runs OK, but only the last plot is returned.

I have tried several do.call(), eval() and parse() combinations but I was not able to do what I wanted: That is, to use the Plot1, Plot2, etc. as names of individual ggplot objects to be saved.

Usually I get errors such as

```
Error in do.call("eval", plotname) <- ggplot(map.df.l, aes(long, lat,  : 
  target of assignment expands to non-language object
```

I have searched stackoverflow, found 
[Multiple ggplots in for loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7452683/multiple-ggplots-in-for-loop) 
but was not able to amend the code - I need to save the plots, not to print them.

Probably I am doing some trivial mistake (I'm not that much of a programmer)... Any comments and suggestions would be highly apreciated. Thank you.

Comment: could you use a list to store them `plots_list <- list(); plots_list[[i]] <- ggplot(...)`

Comment: Yes! It works. Thank you very much!